# unfortunately has stopped error on real device issue

Tags: android

My app works correctly on an emulator, but I get 'unfortunately has stopped' on real devices, especially when I want to go from an activity to another one. I'm searching for an app or something to save logs or anything can help me to find the solution to resolve my issue. Can anyone help me or introduce an app to me, or share your experience about the same problems?

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Also, please read [ask] and create a [mcve] showing the relevant code as well as your logcat.

Comment: Post error log here

Comment: *"I'm searching... for something to save logs"* You mean logcat?

Answer (score 0):

In your android studio at the bottom bar search for `Android Monitor` -> `logcat`. You can find your crash log there by selecting your device.[image: Checkout the screenshot]